# Can I name a type in Crystal for convenience?

Tags: crystal-lang

In my new crystal project, I have a class which is storing its data in a couple of different ways that are useful to me later, both as hashes.

```
getter isometry_cardinality : Hash(IsometryKind, Int8)
getter axis_cardinality : Hash(Directions::Orientation, Array(IsometryKind))
```

I'd like to overload my methods now based on which hash its using:

```
private def has_min_cardinality?(parent_cardinality : Hash(IsometryKind, Int8))
  ...
end

private def has_min_cardinality?(parent_cardinality : Hash(Directions::Orientation, Array(IsometryKind))
  ...
end
```

as you can see, that declaration is getting pretty long. Is there some convenient way to shorten it? For example, can I use the getter as an alias for its type?

```
private def has_min_cardinality?(parent_cardinality : isometry_cardinality)
  ...
end

private def has_min_cardinality?(parent_cardinality : axis_cardinality)
  ...
end
```

The answer is 'no' to *that* specific example, so my question is: am I missing the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way: [`alias`](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/alias.html) to the rescue!

You can alias complex types like in this example and use the alias, the compiler just replaces it outright so there's no performance penalty.

```
alias IsometryCardinality = Hash(IsometryKind, Int8)
alias AxisCardinality = Hash(Directions::Orientation, Array(IsometryKind))
getter isometry_cardinality : IsometryCardinality
getter axis_cardinality : AxisCardinality
...
private def has_min_cardinality?(parent_cardinality : IsometryCardinality)
  ...
end

private def has_min_cardinality?(parent_cardinality : AxisCardinality)
  ...
end
```

Here's a demo: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/4hoh

Comment: Actually to get the desired overload behavior you have to use `type` rather than `alias`

Comment: @JonneHaß That's not true. `type` can only be used inside `lib`.

Comment: I added a link to the language reference in the original answer.

Comment: Why not use the same alias in the getter declarations too, though?